# Facebook API. Delete posts or comments

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to delete one's own posts, or comments which are not published from an application?

Answer (score 2):

In Facebook API you are not allowed to delete comments/post/likes not posted by your application.

Its a good security feature. Image an app gets your authorization and deletes all your posts/comments. In today's world it could mean you have been erased from virtual world. :P